# Get child key and values from JSON array: Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have the following JSON Array stored inside a variable called *fieldsArray*:

```
[
  {
    "Header - Goods Receipt":[
        {"warehouse":{"editableField":"false"}},
        {"documentNo":{"editableField":"true"}}
     ]
  },
  {
    "Lines - Goods Receipt":[
        {"description":{"editableField":"false"}}
     ]
   }
 ]
```

I need to loop through this array, grabbing the "Header - Goods Receipt" first, and then drill down and get it's children ("warehouse" and "documentNo") and the values for their nested "editableField" child keys. So far, I have managed to grab "Header - Goods Receipt", but cannot get to it's children. I have done the following so far:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < fieldsArray.length(); i++) {  
     JSONObject fieldsObject = fieldsArray.optJSONObject(i); 
          
             Iterator<String> iterator = fieldsObject.keys(); 

              while(iterator.hasNext()) { 
                String currentParentKey = iterator.next(); 

                String currentParentKeyProperties = fieldsObject.optString(currentParentKey);

                //I have tried the below code to get to "warehouse" and "documentNo", but it's not working:

                Iterator<String> iteratorTwo = currentParentKeyProperties.keys();
                while(iteratorTwo.hasNext()) {
                    String currentChildKey = iteratorTwo.next();
                    String isEditable = currentParentKeyProperties.getJSONObject(currentChildKey).getString("editableField");
                 }

              }
   }
```

I get the following errors:

```
 error: cannot find symbol
 Iterator<String> iteratorTwo = currentParentKeyProperties.keys();                                                          
 symbol:   method keys()
```

and

```
 error: cannot find symbol
 String isEditable = currentParentKeyProperties.getJSONObject(currentChildKey).getString("editableField");
 method: getJSONObject(String)
```

NOTE: *currentParentKeyProperties* gives the following JSON Array:

```
 [
   {
     "warehouse":{"editableField":"false"}
   },
   {
     "documentNo":{"editableField":"true"}
   }
 ]
```

Brand new to Java - not sure why getJSONObject is not working? I have used it elsewhere in my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not related to Java, you just forgot a step.

> String currentParentKeyProperties =
> fieldsObject.optString(currentParentKey);

is not correct, what you want is to get a JSONObject.

Comment: BlueEOS I tried as you suggested, but I now get this error:                                           
       incompatible types: JSONObject cannot be converted to String.                           
       String currentParentKeyProperties = fieldsObject.getJSONObject(currentParentKey);

Comment: JSONObject currentParentKeyProperties = fieldsObject.getJSONObject(currentParentKey);

Comment: BlueEOS I made the adjustment, but it now says JSONObject["Header - Goods Receipt"] is not a JSONObject.

Comment: Sure, "Header - Goods Receipt" is a JSONArray, use getOject and cast it to JSONArray

Comment: Thanks for your guidance - really helped me solve the issue!